# Apache ServiceMix connection to IBM-Websphere-8.0

Tags: ibm-mq, apache-servicemix

I everybody,

I'm trying to migrate our MQ interface from IBM-Websphere 7.0.0.5 to version 8.0.0.6. As an EJB container we are using Apache Servicemix 7.0.0. 
When switching to the 8.0.0.6 libraries I receive the following error stack:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ibmmq' defined in URL [bundle://231.0:0/META-INF/spring/mq-test.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory' to required type 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory' for property 'connectionFactory'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory] to required type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] for property 'connectionFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)[149:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.17.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)[149:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.17.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)[149:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.17.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)[149:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.17.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)[149:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.17.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)[149:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.17.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636)[149:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.17.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:938)[150:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context:3.2.17.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$1600(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:69)[217:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$4.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:355)[217:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.osgi.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)[217:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.completeRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:320)[217:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor$CompleteRefreshTask.run(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:132)[218:org.springframework.osgi.extender:1.2.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_102]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory' to required type 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory' for property 'connectionFactory'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory] to required type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] for property 'connectionFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:464)[149:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.17.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:495)[149:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.17.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:489)[149:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.17.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1465)[149:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.17.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1424)[149:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.17.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)[149:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.17.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)[149:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.17.RELEASE_1]
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory] to required type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] for property 'connectionFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:267)[149:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.17.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:449)[149:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.17.RELEASE_1]
    ... 19 more
```

The following line is strange for me, and I have no conclusion for it:

> Failed to convert property value of type 'com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory' to required type 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory' for property 'connectionFactory'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory] to required type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] for property 'connectionFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

To install the the features, I used the following features-xml file:

```
<features xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.0.0">
  <feature name='ibm-mq-75' version='7.5.0.0'>
    <bundle start-level='85'>file:o:/tools/IBM/Websphere MQ 75/java/lib/OSGi/com.ibm.mq.osgi.directip_7.5.0.0.jar</bundle>
    <bundle start-level='85'>file:o:/tools/IBM/Websphere MQ 75/java/lib/OSGi/com.ibm.mq.osgi.java_7.5.0.0.jar</bundle>
    <bundle start-level='85'>file:o:/tools/IBM/Websphere MQ 75/java/lib/OSGi/com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.commonservices.j2se_7.5.0.0.jar</bundle>
    <bundle start-level='85'>file:o:/tools/IBM/Websphere MQ 75/java/lib/OSGi/com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.jms_7.5.0.0.jar</bundle>
    <bundle start-level='85'>file:o:/tools/IBM/Websphere MQ 75/java/lib/OSGi/com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.nls_7.5.0.0.jar</bundle>
    <bundle start-level='85'>file:o:/tools/IBM/Websphere MQ 75/java/lib/OSGi/com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.wmq.nls_7.5.0.0.jar</bundle>
    <bundle start-level='85'>file:o:/tools/IBM/Websphere MQ 75/java/lib/OSGi/com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.wmq.prereq_7.5.0.0.jar</bundle>
    <bundle start-level='85'>file:o:/tools/IBM/Websphere MQ 75/java/lib/OSGi/com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.wmq_7.5.0.0.jar</bundle>  
  </feature> 

  <feature name='ibm-mq-80' version='8.0.0.6'>
    <bundle start-level='85'>file:o:/tools/IBM/Websphere MQ 80/java/lib/OSGi/com.ibm.mq.osgi.java_8.0.0.6.jar</bundle>
    <bundle start-level='85'>file:o:/tools/IBM/Websphere MQ 80/java/lib/OSGi/com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.commonservices.j2se_8.0.0.6.jar</bundle>
    <bundle start-level='85'>file:o:/tools/IBM/Websphere MQ 80/java/lib/OSGi/com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.jms.prereq_8.0.0.6.jar</bundle>
    <bundle start-level='85'>file:o:/tools/IBM/Websphere MQ 80/java/lib/OSGi/com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.jms_8.0.0.6.jar</bundle>
    <bundle start-level='85'>file:o:/tools/IBM/Websphere MQ 80/java/lib/OSGi/com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.nls_8.0.0.6.jar</bundle>
    <bundle start-level='85'>file:o:/tools/IBM/Websphere MQ 80/java/lib/OSGi/com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.wmq.nls_8.0.0.6.jar</bundle>
    <bundle start-level='85'>file:o:/tools/IBM/Websphere MQ 80/java/lib/OSGi/com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.wmq.prereq_8.0.0.6.jar</bundle>  
    <bundle start-level='85'>file:o:/tools/IBM/Websphere MQ 80/java/lib/OSGi/com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.wmq_8.0.0.6.jar</bundle>
  </feature> 
</features>
```

The example route looks like followed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:osgix="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi-compendium"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi-compendium http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi-compendium/spring-osgi-compendium.xsd">

  <!--bean id="conFactoryFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactoryFactory" /-->

  <bean id="conFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory" >
    <property name="transportType">
      <util:constant static-field="com.ibm.mq.jms.JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP" />
    </property>
    <property name="hostName" value="gs3-mqsrv-lnx" />
    <property name="port" value="1414" />
    <property name="queueManager" value="qm.gb30.realtime" />
    <property name="channel" value="ch.realtime" /> 
    <property name="useConnectionPooling" value="true" />
  </bean>            

  <bean id="ibmmq" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="conFactory" />
  </bean>

  <camel:camelContext id="ibm-mq-test">

    <!-- Uplink from file -> mq -->
    <camel:route id="mq-uplink">
      <camel:from uri="file:mq/in" />
        <camel:transacted />
        <camel:to uri="ibmmq:lq.gslisa.src1" />
        <camel:log message="Put message into mq!" />
    </camel:route>

    <!-- Downlink from mq -> file -->
    <camel:route id="mq-downlink">
      <camel:from uri="ibmmq:lq.gslisa.src1" />
        <camel:transacted />
        <camel:to uri="file:mq/out" />
        <camel:log message="Read message from mq!" />
    </camel:route>

  </camel:camelContext>

</beans>
```

As described before, using feature: **ibm-mq-75** everything is wokring, changeing this to **ibm-mq-80** displays the error.
Can anybody help?

Thanks, 
Jörg

Comment: It seems, that the problem is caused by mixing the JMS versions: 

ServiceMix uses JMS 1.1 with geronimo-specification- 1.1.1

IBM-MQ lib uses JMS 2.0 which is provided/exported in library: com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.jms.prereq_8.0.0.6.jar

Building a blueprint testcase without using ASM is working as expected.

So how can I tell the interface bundle to use the IBM-jms version instead?

Answer (score 1):

Performing the following steps seem to solve my issue:

1. switching mq-package from camel-jms to camel-sjms
2. forcing servicemix to clean the cache on each startup.